# Remove selection from initialized text (Deselect) in CEdit control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have CEdit control and I don't want any text to be selected by default. I tried using

```
    m_txtURL.SetSel(-1, 0, TRUE);
```

to remove the selection, but to no avail. can some one suggest a way to do achieve that?

I tried to select some characters using the following coding. That too did not work.

```
m_txtURL.SetSel(-1, 0, TRUE);
```

Can someone tell me what the problem could be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I am able to deselect the text in the Edit control. The edit control, I am using is the first control in the Dialog box, so the by default the first control in the dialog box has been set to focus.  From [developers' reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> If OnInitDialog returns nonzero,
>   Windows sets the input focus to the
>   first control in the dialog box. The
>   application can return 0 only if it
>   has explicitly set the input focus to
>   one of the controls in the dialog box.

No what I have done is:

```
BOOL CIegSettingsDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();


    return FALSE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

By this we indicate to dialog box that, we would take care of focussing a control.

Answer (score 0):

The question is why is your text selected by default?

- Subclass it using `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_txtURL)`
- Set the text `m_txtURL.SetWindowText(_T("just some text"))` in `OnInitDialog`

Nothing should be selected.